# Can i find frequency of visit of stores using the information provided?

Tags: python, algorithm, genetic-algorithm

I have a warehouse, which serves 100 stores.

Each store has to be visited N times a month to fulfill its demand.

i'e every day a Van `V` starts from the warehouse `W` , and cover `n` stores in a day(8 hours) and come back to warehouse

I want to find the no. `N` , i'e how many times a store should be visited in a given month to fulfill its demand.

I am gathering what information is needed for every store to calculate its frequency.

I could come up with the following:

1. Sale value of each store(monthly). i.e in this month a store will sell `k` items which will gain them the sale value `s`
2. Total weight of the `k` items.
3. Weight of the Truck

Can this problem be solved by using knapsack algorithm?

If yes, apart from the 3 points, is any other information required at store level?

I have each store to store distance, also warehouse to store distance matrix available.

Below shown is just the snapshot of the data i thought was required, and created a random dataset.

Customer_code = store_code.
[image: sample data]

PS . I am developing in python.

Code to create random dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
from numpy.random import uniform
my_randoms = random.sample(range(1000), 100)
weights = random.sample(range(100), 100)


df = pd.DataFrame({'customer_code':list(range(1,101)),
               'latitude':uniform(24.74272,28.1234,100),
                'longitude':uniform(46.1234,50.123445,100),
               'sale_value':my_randoms,
               'weights':weights})
```

Comment: Please no images, use text. Is this your homework? what have you tried to solve?

Comment: We need to know how far the truck can travel in 8 hours. You've given us the store locations, from which we could determine the distance, but we need to know the truck's average speed and how long it takes to unload the truck at each store. It's unclear if the "sale_value" is the "k" items you're talking about, or if that's the "s" value. It's also unclear if the "weights" value in the table is the total weight of all "k" items, or the weight of each of the "k" items. Please edit your question to clarify the requirements.